# Snowflake Get every key/value from a column that has a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column named monthly_stats (VARCHAR type) with the  below list of dictionaries:

```
    [{"id": 123, "quantity_booked": "12", "budget_booked": "112", "budget_booked_loc": "36.428571"}, 
        {"id": 1288119, "quantity_booked": "1703.3", "budget_booked": "58.694684",
     "budget_booked_loc": "43.434066"}, {"id": 233, "quantity_booked": "1648.35",
 "budget_booked": "56.801307", "budget_booked_loc": "42.032967"}]
```

I've tried this query:

```
 with org_table as (             
    select
    parse_json(monthly_stats) as m
    from my_table
) 
    select
    m[0]:id::integer as monthly_budgets_id,
    from org_table);
```

but this only selects  the first id in the list of dictionaries. how do I get every id in the each dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it like this using `lateral flatten`:

```
set teststring = '[{"id": 123, "quantity_booked": "12", "budget_booked": "112", "budget_booked_loc": "36.428571"},
                    {"id": 1288119, "quantity_booked": "1703.3", "budget_booked": "58.694684", "budget_booked_loc": "43.434066"}]';


 with org_table as (
    select
    parse_json($teststring) as m
)
    select
    flattened.value:id as id
    from org_table,
    lateral flatten( input => m ) as flattened;
```

Comment: this worked, but its giving me duplicate values (18 to be exact) when I run this:
SELECT DISTINCT id, count(*)
FROM my_new_table;
WHERE id = '296467'
GROUP BY 1;

Answer (score 0):

Please review some articles below, that might be of help:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extracting-JSON-using-LATERAL-FLATTEN

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extract-multi-level-JSON-object-using-lateral-flatten

Answer (score 0):

You can get iterate over arrays with `flatten()`:

```sql
with my_table as (
    select
  '[{"id": 123, "quantity_booked": "12", "budget_booked": "112", "budget_booked_loc": "36.428571"}, 
        {"id": 1288119, "quantity_booked": "1703.3", "budget_booked": "58.694684",
     "budget_booked_loc": "43.434066"}, {"id": 233, "quantity_booked": "1648.35",
 "budget_booked": "56.801307", "budget_booked_loc": "42.032967"}]' monthly_stats
    )
 , org_table as (             
    select parse_json(monthly_stats) as m
    from my_table
) 

select x.value:id, x.value:budget_booked
from org_table, table(flatten(m)) x;
```